# Android Compatibility Package on Android 3+

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

There's something I don't get with the compatibility package. You get the APIs of Android 3+ under android 1.x-2.x. Great. But what about an app that you design to be compatible with android 1 to 4?

Let's say I want to develop an app that uses Fragments even on Android 2.x phones. Fine, I'll use the compatibility package. But what about this very app running on ICS? The app will use the compatibility package instead of the native APIs present in the ICS phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the app will use the compatibility package instead of the native APIs. You can test that by debugging an app using the compatibility package and running on ICS; you will see it still uses the compatibility package.

Comment: So we'll have the HC/ICS phones/tablets use compatibility package until android 2.x fades below a threshold (that every one will choose, for example 5%)? That's quite a shame. I didn't think it was that way.
Thanks a lot though Cristian!

Comment: Yeah, it is a shame. What I recommend is starting to build apps for, at least, 2.3 and newer. We developers have to force users to upgrade their phones. We cannot keep compatibility of Android 1.5 for ever!

Comment: 2.3 isn't enough... We'll have to wait a long time before everybody gets ICS. Thank you for your answer! Accepted ;)